# Is it possible to cast Map<Field, Value> to Map<Mirror, Mirror> when it is known that Field and Value extend Mirror?

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

I am trying to cast upwards `Map<Field, Value>` to `Map<Mirror, Mirror>`. 
It makes sense for the cast to work, as both `Field and Value extend Mirror`, however I am getting a `"cannot cast" error`.

Is it simply not possible to `cast Maps with double types`? If so, how else can I cast?

I would appreciate any help!

Thank you,

Dean

Comment: As a side note, this isn't possible as you wrote it because Java's generics are invariant -- that is, `GenericClass<Supertype>` is *not* a superclass of `GenericClass<SubType>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would be possible only if you define the

```
Map<Field, Value>
```

as

```
Map<? extends Mirror, ? extends Mirror>
```

But otherwise, it's not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed it! What does "? extends aClass" mean?

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf: Read a good guide to generics - or the Java Generics FAQ (http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Comment: It means a `Map` of some class which extends `Mirror`. This is necessary because `Map<Sub, Sub>` is not actually a subclass of `Map<Super, Super>`.