# Accept List of objects that extends an object

Tags: java, arraylist

We have a method that accepts a `List` of the type `RectangularShape`.

```
void foo(List<RectangularShape> recs) {
    // ...
}
```

We create an `ArrayList` of the type `Rectangle2D`.

```
ArrayList<Rectangle2D> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
```

Then we try to call the foo method:

```
foo(rectangles);
```

First of all it's not applicable for a `List`, but that's not my main problem. If I change that to `ArrayList` then i get that it's not applicable for `ArrayList<Rectangle2D>`, but why not? Since `Rectangle2D` extends `RectangularShape` in my logic it should be possible.

Comment: Change to `List<Rectangle2D> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();`

Comment: And what you're planning to do is possible if you use `<E extends RectangularShape> void foo(List<E> recs) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the generic bounds, as indicated here: [Is it possible to cast Map<Field, Value> to Map<Mirror, Mirror> when it is known that Field and Value extend Mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232814/is-it-possible-to-cast-mapfield-value-to-mapmirror-mirror-when-it-is-known/24232838#24232838)

More information on how to use generic bounds: [Java generics and casting to a primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574478/java-generics-and-casting-to-a-primitive-type/24575113#24575113)

Basically you need to either use the wildcard operator as

```
void foo(List<? extends RectangularShape> recs) {
  ...
}
```

Or make the method parametric, like this:

```
<E extends RectangularShape> void foo(List<E> recs) {
  ...
}
```

I personally prefer the second approach.

Comment: Even though you can refer to `E`, there is nothing you can do with `E` that you can't do with `RectangularShape`. Less, infact, because you can't access `E.class`, but you can access `RectangularShape.class`.

Comment: @JamieCockburn I see! That's a fair point. Considering the compiler itself can figure out the type of `E` based on the type of the list given to it, is there any functional difference between the two? I can't think of any at the moment.

Comment: @Zhuinden if i use the first approach, how would i get an Iterator?

Comment: @Zhuinden No, there's no difference between the two.  The compiler actually throws away that information, so at runtime, nobody knows what was in-between the <>s.  This is called type-erasure.

Comment: @clankill3r Just use `for (RectangularShape shape : recs)` to iterate the list.

Comment: @clankill3r Or if you want an actual `Iterator` instance, just call `recs.iterator()`

Comment: @Zhuinden I suppose that if you want to declare any locals with the same geneneric type as the list, `Map<Integer, E>` is less verbose that `Map<Integer, ? extends ...>`

Comment: For the Iterator it's this:
`Iterator<? extends RectangularShape> itr = recs.iterator();`

Comment: I think with the second method it's just `Iterator<E> itr = recs.iterator();` so I guess overall it ends up "prettier" and less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your method like this:

```
void foo(List<? extends RectangularShape> l) {
    ... 
}
```

That allows for an argument of a `List` (or any subclass of `List`) of `RectangularShape`s (or any subclass of `RectangularShape`).

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(List<? extends RectangularShape> recs) { // this method accept List 
                         of RectangularShape or it's sub types
}
```

So you have to change

```
ArrayList<Rectangle2D> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
```

In to

```
List<Rectangle2D> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
```

Now `Rectangle2D extends RectangularShape` both type of `List` will be accept by `foo()`

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, the type `List<Rectangle2D>` is still incompatible with `List<RectangularShape>`.