# Generics: how to make the compiler control what type I put into a constructor

Tags: java, generics

This example is taken from Thinking in Java.

```
public class Automobile {
}

public class Holder<T> {
    private T a;
    public Holder(T a){
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void set(T a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public T get(){
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder<Automobile>(new Automobile());
        Automobile a = (Automobile)h.get();
    }
}
```

Then there goes explanation: you must specify what type you want to put into it using the same angle brackets syntax as you can see in main().

Well, I can't understand anything. I would understand that must word as a possible compile time error in case of violation of this rule.

But this works:

```
    Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder(new Automobile());
    Automobile a = h.get();
```

And this works:

```
Holder h = new Holder(new Automobile());
Automobile a = (Automobile)h.get();
```

So, as I can see, the compiler won't control what I put into the Holder object. Well, then I don't catch generics at all. And I have two questions:

1. What is the reason to use them? Only to save me some effort when casting object back to Automobile?
2. Is there any way to make the compiler control me so that I should really put Automobile into the Holder?

Comment: I added two comments, java 1.7 and also fixed an error in the third code snippet, please check the answer after edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The casting here is unnecessary:

```
    Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder<Automobile>(new Automobile());
    Automobile a = (Automobile)h.get();
```

But here it is necessary:

```
Holder h = new Holder(new Automobile());
Automobile a = (Automobile)h.get();
```

And this is the best way of doing things ever since java 1.5 and above:

```
Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder<Automobile>(new Automobile()); //specify the generic parameter on both static and dynamic type
Automobile a = h.get(); //no casting is necessary
```

Or above java 1.7 for simplicity:

```
Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder<>(new Automobile()); //diamond operator so you don't need to respecify the same thing
Automobile a = h.get();
```

The reason why it's useful to use generics in this fashion is so that you can't do the following:

```
Integer a = new Integer(6);
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(a);
list.add("5");
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    Integer integer = (Integer)list.get(i); //crashes at "5" which is String at runtime
    System.out.println(integer);
}
```

As you can see, if you can put any subclass of Object into the list without bounds, then you need explicit casting, and if you put anything that is not what you expect it to be into the List, then it will crash. Please note that without generics, you're also not told what type you are expected to place into the list, which means you need to keep track of what the List is supposed to contain, which is really crappy when you're trying to do logic like the following: [Java generics and casting to a primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574478/java-generics-and-casting-to-a-primitive-type/24575113#24575113)

And I'm not even sure if this is possible without generics: [Is it possible to cast Map<Field, Value> to Map<Mirror, Mirror> when it is known that Field and Value extend Mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232814/is-it-possible-to-cast-mapfield-value-to-mapmirror-mirror-when-it-is-known/24232838#24232838)

So technically generics enable extra features while also encourages type safety and therefore error-less code, which is always nice.

```
Integer a = new Integer(6);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(a);
list.add("5"); //this will not compile -> you won't need to wait until runtime to see that things are incorrect!
```

Comment: "And this is the best way of doing things ever since java 1.5 and above:" I have to disagree. You are using a raw type constructor, which is not safe. The correct way is `Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder<Automobile>(new Automobile());` or (in Java 1.7+) `Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder<>(new Automobile());`. Using the raw type constructor turns off generic type checking. Suppose that the constructor of `Holder<T>` was `public Holder(List<T> a)`, then `Holder<Automobile> h = new Holder(new ArrayList<String>());` would be allowed, even though it is obviously wrong.

Comment: @newacct absolutely correct! Sorry for the error, apparently the constructor parameter messed me up. Fixed. That should not have been a raw type.

Answer (score 0):

The point of generics is to write datastructures which can contain or work with any object. You specify at use-time which types of objects it should contain, e.g.:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

(Diamondoperator for show not written in short)

to answer the questions:
1: to write code which can work with all objects (like the collections), and yes, the compiler understands and can type-check your code at compiletime
2: yeah, dont use generics and instead write the code spezific for your automobiles